# react app with Iframe to MVC protected by IdentityServer4

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-mvc-4, identityserver4

I have a React SPA application and on a particular tab I have an Iframe to display an MVC application. All of this is using Identity Server 4 for authentication. Is there a way so auth token that is being used by the React application can be passed to via Iframe MVC Application?

Comment: How is authentication currently handled in the MVC app? Would it be feasible to add OIDC authentication via a silent `authorize` endpoint redirect?

Comment: @mackie so the MVC application would not be a stand alone application so I'm struggling on how it needs to be setup. It w

Comment: I fat fingered the enter button.....I have it currently setup so that CORS is locked down to only be from the React SPA (App 1). I have client setup as hybrid but really it should accept the token that exists for App1.

Comment: @mackie ok I've got my MVC app showing up using Implicit grant type however, this particular MVC application should never be able to be browsed to directly. As I have it right now since the secret is in the startup.cs you can type in the url and it will self authenticate. I was wanting to set the Client as a scope of the main SPA is that possible or do I need to limit access via IIS?